# Python PIL.Image module seems to conflict with tkinter module (AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open')

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-module

Can anyone help me understand why I get "AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'"  with this code. 
It looks to me really clean.
Odd enough, I also tried to access a global var in reading from the function clicked(), and that did not work (I commented those lines now, but the error is reported in the code). That might be a clue! Yet, I am lost !

Thanks a lot for your help!

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import binascii
import struct
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#import Image
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import scipy.cluster

from tkinter import *

NUM_CLUSTERS = 5


#im=3  #just for testing access to global vars, in second line int he function . Oddly Failed:  "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'im' referenced before assignment"



window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app")
window.geometry('350x200')
lbl = Label(window, text="Hello")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)




def clicked():
    print('reading image')
    #print(im)  #just for testing access to global vars . Oddly Failed:  "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'im' referenced before assignment"
    im = Image.open('image.jpg')
    im = im.resize((150, 150))      # optional, to reduce time
    ar = np.asarray(im)
    shape = ar.shape
    ar = ar.reshape(scipy.product(shape[:2]), shape[2]).astype(float)

    print('finding clusters')
    codes, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(ar, NUM_CLUSTERS)
    print('cluster centres:\n', codes)

    vecs, dist = scipy.cluster.vq.vq(ar, codes)         # assign codes
    counts, bins = scipy.histogram(vecs, len(codes))    # count occurrences

    index_max = scipy.argmax(counts)                    # find most frequent
    peak = codes[index_max]
    colour = binascii.hexlify(bytearray(int(c) for c in peak)).decode('ascii')
    print('most frequent is %s (#%s)' % (peak, colour))

    lbl.configure(text='most frequent is &peak &colour ')

    return

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me to load image.jpg", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `from PIL import Image as PILImage` and from `PIL import ImageTk as PILImageTk`. Then change your code accordingly

Comment: Thank a lot Jammy. That worked!  Still wondering why it did not work, but .. solved!

Comment: As Tkinter has its own image class, it was overwriting PIL's. Changing the import name of PIL's meant it didn't replace it

Comment: @Janko This kind of issue is the reason why it is better to avoid wildcard imports (like `from tkinter import *`) because you don't know what you are importing and if there are naming conflicts. Either do `import tkinter as tk` or import only the tkinter objects you are using.

Comment: @j_4321.. Yes, that make sense! Thanks